# Inject React fragment into a navigation component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I have a simple React App that uses React-Router to navigate between pages. I want to add page-specific navigation items to the global navigation bar.

To do this I am passing a function as a prop to each page component which it can call to pass its own chosen component into the navigation component.

It has to be a component since it will encompass arbitrary buttons and menus with their appropriate handlers.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={ toolbar: null };
        this.setToolBar = this.setToolBar.bind(this);
    }

    setToolBar(toolBar) {
        this.setState({ toolBar });
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <HashRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={loginPage} />
                    <Navigation toolBar={this.state.toolBar} />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} setToolBar={this.setToolBar} />} />
                        <Route path="/pageOne" render={(props) => <PageOne {...props} setToolBar={this.setToolBar} />}  />
                        <Route path="/pageTwo" render={(props) => <PageTwo {...props} setToolBar={this.setToolBar} />} />
                        <Route path="/pageThree" render={(props) => <PageThree {...props} setToolBar={this.setToolBar} />} />
                    </Switch>
                </Switch>
            </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

This works as a concept but as each page has its own routing to lower level pages I am having to pass this function down many levels and am beginning to think that there should be an easier way.

What I would really want to do is to have each page to dispatch a redux action with its own navigation component in the componentDidMount function and have the navigation component subscribe to this and update accordingly.

However I am passing a component and passing non-serializable data to redux is (depending who you believe) at best an anti-pattern and at worst a capital offence.

So, what would be the best way of doing this? If it makes any difference I am using material-ui v1.0 as the UI library.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple possible solutions to bypass storing a component in redux (which I think is fine if that's what your app calls for).

**Option 1:**

Store a component **name** to your redux store instead of the component instance. Then, you can create a `<Toolbar />` component that subscribes to the component name and uses it to render the correct toolbar. The caveat here is that each page will need to create their own unique toolbar component i.e.: `<HomePageToolbar />`, `<PageOneToolbar />`. Your main `<Toolbar />` component will import ALL toolbar components and conditionally render the correct component based on the name passed in:

```
getToolbar = () => {
    switch(this.props.toolbarName) {
        case 'homePage': {
            return <HomePageToolbar />;
        }
        case 'pageOne': {
            return <PageOneToolbar />;
        }
        default: {
            return <DefaultToolbar />;
        }
    }   
};

render () {
    const toolbar = this.getToolbar();
    return (
        <div>
            {toolbar}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Option 2**

Use a unique query param to render the toolbar. Set a `?toolbar=homePage` query param that your `<Toolbar />` component will use to conditionally render the toolbar the same way as above.

**Option 3:**

Just store the component in your redux store and pull it straight from there.

Comment: The problem with options 1 & 2 is that the onClick events need to be bound to the page component and not the navigation.